# Wordpress: Store HTML of InnerBlocks as an attribute of the parent block

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I have created an FAQ block using @wordpress/create-block package.

The question is stored as an attribute however the answer is an `<InnerBlocks>` component. I don't seem to be able to store the HTML value of InnerBlocks as an attribute of the parent. It does not take a `value` or an `onChange` property.

Is there a way to store the rendered HTML of this `<InnerBlocks>` component as an attribute of the parent block.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the ability to read both the question and content attribute in PHP so that I can create a structured data schema (JSON-LD) and place it in wp_head.

Block JSON (attributes):

```
"content": {
            "type": "string" 
        },
"question": {
            "type": "string",
            "selector": "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6"
        },
```

Edit.js (just the relevant parts)

```
<RichText
  onChange={(_question) =>
    setAttributes({ question: _question }) }
  value={question}
/>
<InnerBlocks
  onChange={(_content) =>
    setAttributes({ content: _content }) }   // property doesn't exist 
  value={content}   // property doesn't exist
```

Assuming this is not possible, I have been using the `render_block` filter where I can extract the attribute for the question (`$block['attrs']['question']`). However the content is contained within `$block['innerBlocks']` and the HTML is further in `['innerHTML']`. Whilst I can extract it this way, if the `<InnerBlocks>` is nesting further InnerBlocks (such as a group or column) this requires a function to loop through each potential nesting and each potential nesting of a nesting etc.... It seems overly burdensome for something so simple.

Is there another way?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with gutenberg, but one word does come to mind " Quotes ".  Putting something that can contain quotes like HTML, is usually not a good idea inside something that uses quotes to define it like an attribute.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You are entirely correct. So I suppose it needs to be extracted using the loop I have suggested.

Comment: it's also possible to encode the data somehow, such as base64 that would avoid the encoding issues..  However I feel I should mention that you should always be careful about injecting anything into an attribute for XSS type attacts.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That is an option. I just rather assumed that this wasn't a unique problem and that there is a documented way of doing it. I could also use an output buffer but again it seems like there should be a proper way of doing this.

Comment: That I don't know, I've done a lot of wordpress development but I've largely avoided using Gutenberg, it's not on purpose.  It's just never been something I needed to use yet... lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I haven't used Wordpress in about ten years and am a bit rusty. If we take your non gutenberg knowledge. How would you go about this. Let's say you've created a shortcode or custom fields that shows some questions and answers. They display as intended but now you want to use the value of each question and the value of each answer to create a script in wp_head. How would you go about accessing the data?

Comment: personally I would include the JavaScript I needed as part of the HTML that I am generating.  Like with a simple `<script>` tag following the HTML.   It's not as clean but it's easier to maintain because it's not in a separate place that needs to be looked for, if that makes sense.   In other words I would include everything it needs when rendering the HTML.  The only issue with this is, if you are generating duplicate HTML blocks.  But it's hard for me to judge the specific requirements.  It's just there is no law saying it has to go in the header, and it's easier to find later.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I thought of this too but I am generating more than one FAQ block in different sections on different pages. I have managed to override the render function and do what I want, it's just this ridiculous innerBlock in innerBlock (possible many more) situation. I need to run a script that extracts an innerHTML tag, checks for an innerBlocks tag, if there is one, looks for an innerHTML tag then checks for an innerBlock tag etc... etc.. It seems quite silly but it is working at the moment.

Comment: maybe you misworded it or I missunderstand, but thinking this violates the  Server -> client relationship.  `but now you want to use the value of each question and the value of each answer to create a script in wp_head`  In that you cant create a script in the header after rendering the page.  So you have to create that script when rendering the page.  Putting it in the header means that you would actually need the script before rendering the page.  I'm sure you probably know this, but it is important to remember

Comment: ` I thought of this too but I am generating more than one FAQ block in different sections on different pages` - I feel this is all the more reason to "Containerize it".  You just have to be careful of duplicate Javascript.  I would probably generate a random ID or something to limit the effect of each piece of JS to the container its for.  That way each block has everything it needs to function with no dependencies.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Not exactly. In theory I should put it in the wp_foot but the render function appears to be called when a post is saved as apposed to when it is created on the page (at least with non-dynamic blocks which this is). Whether I am correct with that belief or not what I have done is working anyway. After extracting the data it is then inserted into wp_head with add_action and at least that bit is absolutely working as intended.

Comment: If it loads the blocks -via- AJAX, Than your options are limited because the server has already rendered the page.  This is what I meant about the Server -> Client relationship.  It's only one way.  I sort of remember something about this for Gutenberg, but don't quote me on it...  ( that it loads blocks through AJAX )  If that is the case the normal  Templating and theme hooks wont work, such as `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: However, the render function is part of the save process of the page and not part of the render process of the page to the end user despite the name. Therefore so long as the data is grabbed during the save process it is still a PHP variable and can be accessed by add_action outside the render function still before anything has actually been delivered on the front end. Trust me this bit does work.

Comment: I leave you with this one tp try and simplify my code. I haven't played with PHP for years so hopefully this is a simple one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77143767/php-get-the-value-of-every-occurrence-of-a-key-in-a-multidimensional-array